# Arduino powering another curcuit

Tags: arduino, transistors

I'm trying to use my arduino to control my car's simple key fob which is controlled by a 3v battery and probably draws a very small current. I am controlling it with bluetooth from my phone.
As a noob in circuitry, I researched how to use transistors so I can use a transistor to trigger the push button (the rubbery kind, just connecting + and - when you press it) and I believe I wired it up correctly.
My test works when I hook it up to an LED but whenever I try to trigger the 3rd wire on the transistors I soldered onto the remote buttons, they don't complete the circuit and send the signal.
I tried using resistors to limit the voltage/current going to the remote down from 5v to a lower amount but I'm not even sure if that is the issue.

- 5v is going to + on the key fob.
- ground is going to - on key fob and neg wires on the transistors that are on the buttons.
- positive on transistors is wired to the + connector on the buttons
  third transistor wire is connected to digital outs on the arduino, which are enabled for 1 second when pressed in the app, and tested on the LED to verify they are coded properly.

My question is:
What is the issue with my circuitry?
Does anyone have an idea what I could be doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: You cannot use a transistor to fake a button push until you figure out the circuitry of the target device.  It may expect the input to go high or low or respond only when driven with a scanning pulse.

Comment: Don't use a transistor. Replace the transistor with an optocoupler (the circuit has to be modified, too; this is not a pin-for-pin replacement) and try again. Please mind that I'm not saying that this would work with an optocoupler.

Comment: @mguima Hmm I watched a video about the octocoupler. It seems like that should solve my issue, so I'll buy some of those and give it a try. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Good luck! If you have other questions, I (and most of folks in EE.SE) would be glad to help. But, seriously, do you really intend to build a device for opening / closing your car's doors, controlling it with Bluetooth from your phone? I hope that you are doing this **just as an experiment**, and you will not let this circuit permanently connected, will you? I have 30+ years as an electronics hobbytst, and I've already built some very complex circuits... I do really envy the "courage" (or, would it be cluelessness?) of a newbie thinkering with something critical as a vehicle.

Comment: @mguima Noo I'm not connecting to my car's wiring (at least not yet), just the key fob which cost me $15 on amazon, so it's not a big deal, however if I did end up persuing electronics inside my car I'd definitely make sure I did the proper research, either way, it's an older car with fairly simple circuitry (for example, my LED headlights draw less current than halogen and cause issues closing (pop up headlights) because it's just that basic circuitry in the car), and overall I don't think I'd be risking too much haha. I appreciate the warm welcome too though!

Comment: I understood that you are using just a key fob. Even so, I can think of: a) bluetooth cheap modules can be hacked, some of them don't even use password; b) misfunctions in the system could drain the battery; c) misfunction in the system could make it permanently trigger the transmitter, and this would prevent you from using other fob (with two fob transmitters on, the receiver can't listen to any of them). **As long as you are aware of all of this (and always keeps the real physical key with you)**, is a nice thing to make those hacks, and make an old car seems partially like a Tesla! ;-)